# Equality from the Grothendieck inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

I asked the following [question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4544882/64809) but have not received any response. So I would like to try my luck here.

This question is related to the [Grothendieck inequality](https://www.thenetworkcenter.nl/uploaded_files/inlineitem/JB_grothendieck_proof.pdf). Let field $\mathbb F$ be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and $m,n\in \mathbb N$. What $M\in \mathbb F^{m\times n}$ would satisfy the following equality?
$$
\max_{\|x_i\|=\|y_j\|=1} \sum_{i,j} M_{i,j} \langle x_i, y_j \rangle  = \max_{|s_i|=|t_j|=1} \sum_{i,j} M_{i,j} s_i t_j,
$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product in a Hilbert space and $\|\cdot\|$ is the 2-norm in that space, and $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value in $\mathbb F$.

$uM$ where $|u|=1$ satisfies this equality, for any $M$ satisfying this equality. A positive matrix $M$ where $M_{i,j}\ge0,\,\forall i,j$ obviously satisfies this inequality. So does a rank $1$ matrix. What is the characterization of all such $M$?

Comment: You probably should wait more than eight hours before giving up on responses on MSE... :)